# What is OPAM's shell hook?

Tags: opam

During initialization of OPAM I got this message:

> A hook can be added to opam's init scripts to ensure that the shell
>   remains in sync with the opam environment when they are loaded. Set
>   that up? [y/N]

Could you clarify what does this mean?

I've tried to find out it here: https://github.com/ocaml/opam/search?q=hook&unscoped_q=hook

I heard this word before, but what is "shell hook"? What it is used for? Why it asks me to choose? :)

Answer (score 1):

[env_hook.sh](https://github.com/ocaml/opam/blob/e81a8de481b36e6ce4848580f94dee61bdc0059e/src/state/shellscripts/env_hook.sh) adds the hook, at least in bash, scripts for other shells are similar.
This will run `eval $(opam env)` every time the prompt is displayed.
You can run `opam env` and check what it does, it sets some environment variables.

You need this hook for local switches, it will update the switch based on your current directory. See issue [#3573](https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues/3573) for discussion about this topic.

It's possible to change this configuration option later, just re-run `opam init`.